# When can the standard library functions throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, std, standard-library

I'm having trouble understanding which functions from the standard library can throw exceptions, and if so which and when.

Some functions are `noexcept`, in which case ok they don't, but if I look for example at `std::string::operator[]()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at, the operator is not `noexcept` yet the page says nothing about exceptions (and same [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) so it should have nothing to do with `std::basic_string` being a template).

Can I assume that if no exception is listed on a page then it means that the function cannot throw (but was not marked as `noexcept` for some reason)? Or does it mean the function can throw implementation-defined exceptions? And when exceptions are listed, are they the only ones that can be thrown?

Edit:

- Someone remarked that I should refer to the actual standard and not cppreference for my question, and kindly provided me a relevant link.
- In my example the relevant page would be this one: https://eel.is/c++draft/string.access which explicitly states `Throws: Nothing` for `operator[]()`
- That being said, a few lines below is `front()`, which is not `noexcept` and doesn't have a `Throws` entry in its description, so my question still stands

Comment: [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) definetly shouldn't be throwing an exception, at least, if the implementation of the C standard library is used, but it has no `noexcept` specifier, since C has no exceptions. This means there are at least some cases where the `noexcept` specifier is missing and the function cannot throw an exception.

Comment: @fabian same for `std::abs`, which I link to in the question, but the core of my question is about what is guaranteed by the standard no matter the implementation

Comment: "Can I assume that if no exception is listed on a page then it means that the function cannot throw (but was not marked as noexcept for some reason)?" - I don't think that's a valid assumption - cppreference is good, but it is not [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/). Also, since not all function signatures may have been updated since `noexcept` was added to the language (I'm almost certain they forgot some functions). And btw, a function marked `noexcept` *can* throw exceptions, `noexcept` just means that if it does so then `std::terminate` will be invoked.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I mean, `noexcept` doesn't mean `throw` can't be called, but it does mean no exception can leave the function (because `std::terminate` is called). Regarding the standard, I didn't know there was something I can consult online without purchasing the actual standard. I'll edit my question

Comment: `std::basic_string::operator[]()` has *undefined behaviour* if its argument (index) is out of bounds - which neither disallows nor requires throwing an exception.  In fact, in some debugging builds of some implementations of the standard library, it *does* throw - which is a behaviour that is allowed, but would be implicitly disallowed if it was `noexcept`. In comparison `std::basic_string::at()` does bounds checking and throws an exception if its argument (index) is out of bounds, so avoids undefined behaviour but must do bounds checking.    The other standard containers do things similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to read between the lines.

The string `operator[]` has a *precondition* that the index must be valid. cppreference says:

> If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behavior includes throwing exceptions. And, in fact, some implementations will throw an out-of-range exception in debug mode.

The math functions, like `std::abs`, originally come from the C library. Even though the C library doesn't throw exceptions, it also doesn't say `noexcept` for any of the functions, so to be compatible neither does C++.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable reason for the function not to be marked `noexcept` (although the actual standard says `Throws: Nothing`, cf. my edit, so maybe not), but that only answers half the question: if the precondition is verified, is it guaranteed that the function throws no exception, or is there no guarantee ? (for example, if the precondition is verified, is the implementation allowed to rely on a call to `new` which could throw an exception if the system is out of memory?)

Comment: It is complicated-er. Preconditions don't *have to be* verified by the library. That type of requirement is called Mandates. :-) http://eel.is/c++draft/structure#specifications-3

Comment: @Eternal If the call satisfies the precondition, and there is a `Throws: Nothing` clause in the specification, then it is not allowed to throw. (If there is no such clause, it is allowed to.) But that doesn't mean that it can't use e.g. `new`. It would just have to catch and suppress any exception it might throw to not reach the caller of the library function. And it would then likely have to have a fallback to still satisfy the library call's specified behavior, so if it is reasonable that `new` or such may be used in an implementation, then there likely won't be a `Throws: Nothing` clause.

Comment: @user17732522 You're right. I meant calling it without catching. The last part of your comment seems directly related to my question, i.e. whether the function is allowed to throw or not, and what, if there is no `Throws` clause. Could you make that into an answer and expand a bit on it?

Comment: @Eternal I don't have time right now. The answer would basically be paraphrasing of https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling (+ being allowed to do _anything_ including throwing exceptions if a precondition is violated, which this answer already covers)

Comment: @user17732522 That *does* answer my question, thank you! If you create an answer with that link and a quote containing paragraph 4, I'll make it the accepted answer